# add parent tag of maven in sbt

Tags: maven, sbt, parent-pom

How to add equivalent parent tag of maven in sbt?

For example, below is declared in pom.xml. How to add this in build.sbt.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

Full pom is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>org.example.ms</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
libraryDependencies += "org.springframework.boot" % "spring-boot-starter-parent" % "2.2.5.RELEASE" pomOnly()

libraryDependencies += "org.springframework.boot" % "spring-boot-starter-web" % "2.2.5.RELEASE"

javacOptions ++= Seq("-source", "1.8")
```

above worked for me

Comment: one of the best things about having a spring-boot parent is having dependency manager on the parent pom so you don't need to pass the spring-boot library's versions, so is there a way in sbt to not passing the versions and tell it to use the version from parent pom?

Comment: @SeyedAliRoshan : Not sure. Please let me know, how it can be done in sbt